# imagehtmlemail sending as text/plain

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons, apache-commons-email

we have some code that uses imagehtmlemail, from apache commons.  From most machines it works perfectly, sends out a html email with an embedded image - but from some machines - with exactly the same code, exactly the same smtp server, and inside the same networks - it sends the multipart email as normal - but each of the parts is marked as text/plain - as opposed to having a text/html and text/plain section when it works. And of course the users get a page full of html markup as the result.

I can't see how this is possible.  In code we are using setHtmlMsg of course - and from other machines the same code works - so it must be something environmental or configuration on the machine itself - but nothing I can determine.   Any ideas of either what could be the problem, or what I should check?

Answer (score -1):

we upgraded the apache commons library and the problem went away - so it must have just been a bug :(